# Selenium find elements by xpath and click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I have this line of code:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
...
games1=[]
for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[starts-with(@class,'icon_flag')]"):
 if x.text!="":
  games1.append(x.get_attribute('class'))
```

Then i am trying to make selenium click the elements i found :

```
for x in games1:
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class=x]").click()
```

How is it possible to get error message:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

It really weird since i found the elements from the site!

Comment: Add some console.log statements to narrow in on the cause...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass x as a variable. Right now you are passing the literal "x" value

```
for x in games1:
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class="+x+"]").click()
```